# Sending php mail to csv list

Tags: csv, php, fgetcsv

Im trying to write a simple script to send a message to .csv list of e-mail addresses like this:

```
mail1@mail.com,
mail2@mail.com,
mail3@mail.com,
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
<?
$csv = array();
$file = fopen('test.csv', 'r');

while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){
$csv[] = $result;   

$to          = $result[0];

$subject = "My mail subject";


$message .= '<html><body>';
$message .= 'My message here';
$message .= "</body></html>";


$from = "example@example.com";
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

But the message is sent three times, and includes the message three times in the body. How can I make the message only be included and sent one time to each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove $subject, $message, $from and $headers definition from the while loop. Define all of them before and in the while define only the $to field and keep the mail() command.

Answer (score 0):

Either follow the above suggestion (good approach) or simply remove concatenation operator "." form first assignment to variable $message i.e. change

```
$message .= '<html><body>'; TO
$message = '<html><body>';
```

Comment: By "above suggestion" I meant suggestion provided by Lelio Faieta